# Finding grid start outside of rectangle

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an "infinite" grid of points with spacing of `dx` between columns and `dy` between rows. I have a point which is a point in that grid and a rectangle. I need to get the first row/column outside of the rectangle.
Like:

```
*    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    .    .    .
   _____________________________
* |  .    .    .    .    .    . |  *    .    0    .
  |                             |
* |  .    .    .    .    .    . |  *    .    .    .
  |                             |
* |  .    .    .    .    .    . |  *    .    .    .
  |_____________________________|
*    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    .    .    .

.    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .
```

I need to get the `*` using the coordinates of the rectangle, the coordinates of the `0`, and the spacing of the rows/columns. everything is in floating point values. I tried to do this using modulus but it got really messed up and complicated and I rather not post it.
How can I do this in c++? (I can and prefer to use c++11).
I need it to iterate over it to get all points inside the rectangle (as I'm drawing lines between points, I need the points outside of the rectangle too and I clip the lines to the rectangle).

Comment: If I asked you to find the lowest multiple of 12 that's greater than 53, how would you calculate it?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I tried that approach but that got really complicated because of the "shift" around the point.

Comment: +1 for some of the finest ascii art I've seen in a while. (Well, okay, I think the question is well-asked, but the graphic is surely nice.)

Comment: @Dani: You can treat the "0" as the origin, just subtract it's coordinates from those of the rectangle before you start.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: and how do I calculate "the lowest multiple of 12 that's greater than 53" without using loops (I'm sure there must be a way, I just don't find it)

Answer (score 1):

If the lower left corner coordinates are (x, y), then you can first rebase them by calculating

```
double xb = x / dx;
double yb = y / dy;
```

Then you get to the grid point in this rebased coordinate system just by taking floor:

```
xb = floor(xb);
yb = floor(yb);
```

Finally, you map back to original coordinates:

```
xb = xb * dx;
yb = yb * dy;
```

And this is now the lower left grid point in the original coordinate system that's outside your rectangle's lower left corner.

If this doesn't make sense, consider that in the special case of dx=1, dy=1 the grid points correspond with integers and you can get "to" grid points by floor() and ceil(). When dx and dy differ from 1, you first divide by them to enter a rebased coordinate system where you can use floor() and ceil() to get to the lattice points, and then map back.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the lowest multiple of X that is greater than Y (assuming X and Y are positive `int`s: cast as appropriate):

```
((Y / X) + 1) * X
```

If you add Oli's suggestion of adjusting for the origin before you begin, you eliminate the issue of negatives.

Finally, you can extend the calculation above to allow floating point by a well-placed cast:

```
((int)(Y / X) + 1) * X
```

This now returns the first multiple of a floating point X greater than floating point Y.

Comment: 8 is indeed the greatest multiple of 4 that is GREATER THAN 8. That is what Dani asked.